# Displaying Grouped_data in Python

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I've used the following code to group a certain variable revenue, in my dataset **dd**:

```
group_date=dd.groupby(['Month','Year','PartId'])['revenue'].sum().unstack
```

Since there are about 20k rows, I would like to observe the groups selectively..say for month=1, year=2010 etc and so on. I've tried slicing but it says:

```
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `unstack` is a method or function. It needs to be called e.g. `.unstack()`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. How do I call it?

Comment: With `()`. Without them you are trying to slice a method which makes no sense.

Comment: Right, now how do I print it for Month==1?